# What is the term for the category of words that request someone else do something

Tags: semantics

Is there a term for words/phrases which request that someone do something, such as "contact us", "do this", "click here", "share your thoughts" etc.

Comment: Imperative might be what you're thinking of.

Comment: Hortative? Deontic?

Comment: The technical cover term for all of imperatives, requests, pleas, suggestions, etc. is ***Impositive***, a term coined by Georgia Green Morgan. The idea is that an impositive performative predicate **imposes on** the listener; in practice, it imposes the will of the speaker, though there are many ways to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These sentence types are called imperatives.

E.g.,

Dormez-vous.

Give me that.

Shut up.

etc.

Comment: Which covers a subset of "requests that someone do something", and doesn't include questions like "Can you help?" or declaratives like "It would be helpful if you put the dishes away". That's why Green's concept *impositive* is a better match.

Comment: Since the asker wants "a term for words/phrases which request that someone do something", not really a name for SENTENCES expressing requests, 'imperative' does not seem to me particularly appropriate. I would suggest 'injunctive(s)', a general term often used to refer to expressions of ANY category that play an 'injunctive' role.